# Copying many cells to one location

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I transfer data around a lot in Excel. I want to be able to copy many random cells to another location so that they are side by side.

E.g. I want to copy a3,d21,aa32,cd121,etc. so that a3->a1000,d21->b1000,aa32->c1000,etc.

Is there an easy way to do this besides copying them one by one and going back and forth taking a long time looking up each of these random cells?

The kind of answer I am hoping for:
I go look up these cells(a3,d21,etc.) and select them one at a time so that they are all selected in an order. Then I do "some command" and then click a1000 and they are all copied over side by side.

If Excel is not able to do this sort of operation, what if these "random" cells I am copying are in the same row and separated by a fixed distance.
E.g. (3 apart)
a6,d6,g6,j6,m6,etc. ->  a10,b10,c10,etc.

Part 2.)

What if instead of copying them over side by side, I want to copy them over so that they are, say, k columns apart for some positive integer k.

E.g.
(k=4)
a3,d21,aa32,cd121,etc. ->  a1000,e1000,i1000,m1000,q1000, etc.

or if that is not possible, what about cells in the same row j apart to k apart.

E.g.
(j=3,k=4)
a6,d6,g6,j6,m6,etc. ->  a10,e10,i10,m10,q10, etc.

Comment: It's time for some VBA!

Answer (score 0):

VBA is your friend. If, for some reason, VBA is not an option, you can split screen and look at your source cells at the top and destination at the bottom (or vice versa).

Split vertically (by a horizontal line):
[image: Split vertically (by a horizontal line)]

The opposite:
[image: The opposite]

The end result with 4 separate screens:
[image: The end result with 4 separate screens]

Answer (score 0):

If you never tried VBA, I will provide my sample code. As you had many options in your question, I am sure, after analyzing the code you will be able to adapt it to your needs. I've commented that too in order to help you learn.

First, create a new module (**Insert** > **Module**)

And then put the code inside:

```
Option Explicit   ' no matter what, this is a must have line in every case

Sub test()

    ' declaring variables
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Const k As Long = 4 ' this is the k from your example
    Dim cell As Range

    ' choosing source cells
    Set rngSource = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Choose cells, use Ctrl", Type:=8)
    ' choosing destination cell
    Set rngTarget = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the 1st target cell", Type:=8)

    ' iterating through every cell in Source selection
    i = 0
    For Each cell In rngSource
        ' writing value
        rngTarget.Offset(0, i).Value = cell.Value
        i = i + k
    Next

End Sub
```

For some reason you can't see colors here. But in VBE you will see them.

Good luck!